# Problems whit upload <maxLenght> asp.net 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-4.5, iis-8

I am searching for whole the internet and I cant find one way working about the requirements.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Create(Albums albums)
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "album", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

            <div>Please select some files</div>
        <input name="data" type="file"/>

<system.web>

<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1536000" />

<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1536000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

If I clear this fields the problem is

```
HttpException (0x80004005): Maximum request length exceeded.
```

If clear all modifications on web.config and send a 14k files, all works great.

If I use only

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1536000" />
```

infinite upload at(0%) and Controller is not activated.

Comment: You are using HttpPost? how are you uploading content?

Comment: I fix somethings... (FormMethod.Post)
I commented <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1536000" /> and get value down of <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1536000" /> but now I have a Sending file 0% and nothing is happing.

Comment: You will need to post some more info about what you are trying to do for people here to help out. This includes posting more code/configuration in the context of the problem.